# Why doesn't Lattice Diamond use the sdc file?

Tags: lattice-diamond

I have inherited a Lattice Diamond project. Things seem to be fine, excpet for the systems constraints file. In the Lattice Diamon file list, the sdc file I have shows as greyed out.

Right clicking provides a menu with "set as active", however that option is also greyed out.

I have attempted to make a new one with the same text as the old one:

```
# ##############################################################################
# iCEcube SDC
# Version:            2013.12.25022
# File Generated:     Dec 2 2014 13:31:26
# ##############################################################################
####---- CreateClock list ----1
create_clock  -period 12.50 -name {CLK_IN} [get_ports {CLK_IN}]
```

But the same thing happens, Lattice Diamond refuses to let me use it.

I can create an fdc file, and I get the same issue. I also need to use the sdc file due to internal pollicies.

Despite various internet and stack exchange searches, I have found nothing about this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer! Just a few minuets of searching later!

As stated in the Lattice Diamond User Guide (August 2013), page 47:

> An .sdc file or .fdc file can be added to an implementation if the selected
> synthesis tool is Synplify Pro or Precision. If the selected synthesis tool is the
> Lattice Synthesis Engine (LSE), which is available for MachXO/2 and
> Platform Manager devices, a Lattice design constraint (.ldc) synthesis file can
> be added. Constraints in the .ldc file use the Synopsys constraint format.

A quick test shows this: setting the synthesis tool to Synplify Pro lets me use the sdc file, setting it to Lattice LSE doesn't let me use the sdc file, it only accepts ldc files.